# Regex: how to find a string followed by a non alphanumeric

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to use a regular expression (in php) to find a specific string which must be followed by a non-alpha numeric character (case insensitive).

```
Example String:
Doggy is a lazy dog! Doggy. Dog and I.

Search String: Dog

Expected Result:
Doggy is a lazy <a href="">dog</a>! Doggy. <a href="">Dog</a> and I.
```

So it shouldn't match 'Doggy' because the Dog substring isn't followed by a non-alpha numeric character.

I'm trying something along these lines, but it's not doing exactly what I want.

```
preg_replace("/(dog)[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\p]/i/", "", $str);
```

Comment: Why do you have `\s` in the list of characters to exclude? Then you won't match `Dog` followed by space.

Comment: Are you actually just trying to search for an **exact word match**?? Not "a string followed by a non-alphanumeric"?

Comment: How about using `\b` the word boundary pattern?

Comment: ...In which case, you could just do `preg_replace("/\bdog\b/i", "", $str);`

Comment: `/i/` is going to cause issues, you are double delimiting, I assume thats just a typo here though? Also `\p` will causes issues on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you're *actually* trying to do here is perform an **exact word match**. Not necessarily "a string followed by a non-alphanumeric".

You can achieve this with the `\b` "word boundary" regex anchor:

```
$search = "dog"
preg_replace("/\b".$search."\b/i", "", $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is almost spot on, but there are a few errors:

1. I assume you want to match `Dog` with a space after it, if so, remove the `\s`
2. `\p` isn't a valid regex character.
3. You shouldn't have an extra slash after the `\i`. `\i\` -> `\i`
4. The way your regex currently is, it'll remove the non-alphanumeric character, you can remedy this by surrounding it in a capture group.

You also have no code to add the anchor tags (`<a href=""></a>`).

So, I've gone and compiled all these into the statement below:

```
preg_replace("/(dog)([^a-zA-Z0-9])/i", '<a href="">$1</a>$2', $str);
```

This returns:

```
Doggy is a lazy <a href="">dog</a>! Doggy. <a href="">Dog</a> and I.
```